# 40.000 instances of same texture with different cropping – only 35 fps

Tags: canvas, pixi.js

In `PIXI` I am drawing a circle and using that circle in a texture.
I am thene creating 40.000 sprites using the same baseTexture.

If I'm using 20.000 sprites I get around 60fps but with 40.000 I'm at 35fps. Is there a better way of using the same texture but with different cropping?

***Here is code sample:***

```js
window.onload = () => {

const app = new PIXI.Application({ width: 800, height: 800 });
const stats = new Stats();
stats.showPanel(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.right = '50%';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
// stats = addStats(document, app);
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const lineWidth = 40;
const numX = 200;
const numY = 200;

const width = 600;
const height = 600;

const stepX = width / numX;
const stepY = height / numY;

const circleGraphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
circleGraphics.lineStyle(lineWidth, 0xffffff);
circleGraphics.drawCircle(400, 400, 300 - lineWidth * 0.5);
const circleTexture = app.renderer.generateTexture(circleGraphics);

let array = [];
for (let y = 0; y < numY; y++) {
  array[y] = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < numX; x++) {
    const texture = new PIXI.Texture(circleTexture.baseTexture);
    texture.frame = new PIXI.Rectangle(stepX * x, stepY * y, stepX, stepY);
    const sprite = new PIXI.Sprite.from(texture);
    app.stage.addChild(sprite);
    sprite.x = x * stepX + 100;
    sprite.y = y * stepY + 100;
    sprite._x = sprite.x;
    sprite._y = sprite.y;
    array[y][x] = sprite;
  }
}

let c = 0;

app.ticker.add(() => {
  for (let y = 0; y < numY; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < numX; x++) {
      const item = array[y][x];
      item.x = item._x + Math.sin(c) * 100 * (x / numX);
      item.y = item._y + Math.cos(c) * 120 * (y / numY);
    }
  }
  c += 0.1;
  stats.update();
});


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/5.1.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r16/Stats.min.js"></script>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/lassse/pen/KKWOPeY)

Comment: Hmm i would suggest to ask also about this in the Pixi.js project github: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues